# How to use pageMessages and have exceptions in controller tests

Tags: unit-test, controller, exception, custom-controller

So I know how to present an exception as a message to the user:

```
public class MyController {
    public PageReference myMethod() {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a test for my controller method:

```
@isTest
private class MyControllerTest {
    private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        MyController c = new MyController();
        c.myMethod();
    }
}
```

If doSomething() throws an exception it will be catched and presented as a page message to the user. But what about the test? The method will be called in the test and the exception will be catched - and the page message is nowhere to be seen. But obviously there is an exception that I cannot catch in the test because it is already handled in myMethod().

How do I write tests for this so I can catch these errors?

Comment: Check out the ApexPages Class documentation, specifically `hasMessages()`. Check for no message, execute your method, check for messages being present and the content of the message

Comment: What testing do you have around `doSomething()`?  I'd try to test it independently, then a 'wrapper' test to ensure the page is handling it correctly.

Comment: If've seen `hasMessages()` before but I thought that there must be a better way but it seems that this is the way to go. I like both of your approaches and I'm pretty close to a solution that works for me. Still sad that there's no real out-of-the-box solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've come up with:

```
private class AssertException extends Exception {}

private static void throwIfPageError() {
    List<ApexPages.Message> pageMessages = ApexPages.getMessages();

    if (pageMessages.size() > 0) {
        ApexPages.Message msg = pageMessages[0];
        if (msg.getSeverity() == ApexPages.Severity.ERROR ||
            msg.getSeverity() == ApexPages.Severity.FATAL) {
            throw new AssertException(msg.getSummary());
        }
    }
}

public static void assertPageMessage(String expMsg) {
    try {
        throwIfPageError();
    } catch (AssertException e) {
        System.assertEquals(expMsg, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void assertPage(PageReference expRef, PageReference actRef) {
    throwIfPageError();

    String expectedUrl = expRef.getUrl();
    String actualUrl = actRef.getUrl();

    System.assertEquals(expectedUrl, actualUrl);
}
```

This way I can just assert a certain error message:

```
assertPageMessage('Sorry. Line Items cannot be empty.');
```

And for an extra bonus I can assert pages too:

```
PageReference pageRef;
assertPage(Page.MyPage, pageRef);
```

The only drawback of this solution is that you cannot assert an error, fix the error and assert again with no error because the page messages cannot be cleared. There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZLADAA4) to fix this - but so far nothing has happenend since 2012. The only workaround for this is to use separate tests (one for each error and one for no errors) for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code to assert if page message to be properly displayed. Create a dataset for which it can generate error message in doSomething() method.

```
@isTest
private class MyControllerTest {
  private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    MyController c = new MyController();
    c.myMethod(); 

    List<Apexpages.Message> msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();
    boolean isErrorMessage = false;
    for(ApexPages.Message msg : msgs)
    {
        if (msg.getSummary().contains('Your Error Message') )
        {
            isErrorMessage  = true;
        }
    }       
    //Assert that the Page Message was Properly Displayed
    System.assert(isErrorMessage);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's very similiar to the solution I've come up with looks like. I'll keep you updated what works best for me.

Comment: I like to have all my messages start with some `code` like `[XX-22] Foo must not have a Bar` and then simply verify `[XX-22]`. Furthermore, it is efficient to display the actual error messages generated in the assert's second parameter to save on diagnostic time

Comment: Interesting approach - I will try implementing it. :)